# mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification between two private queue contexts

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, merge, magicalrecord

in my application I call a server API to get a list of users. I display these users in a UITableView with a NSFetchedResultsController. Some users are in contact with the user currently connected and others are not. First I present you my Core Data stack (using MagicalRecord) :
[image]

I manage to show all users (contacts and not contacts) with a `usersContext` where I create/update/delete all users from web service. Any time I save the tableView is updated. This is working fine.

But I wanted to merge the usersContext to the contactsContext in order to save only contacts in store to directly show them the next time the app is launched. Here comes my problem. When I `contactsContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` no users are saved (and of course there are contacts). Maybe my Core Data stack or my code is wrong :

```
// init
- (void)configureContactsStack
{
    _contactsContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator:[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_defaultStoreCoordinator]];
    [_contactsContext MR_setWorkingName:@"Contacts context"];

    _usersContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextWithParent:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
    [_usersContext MR_setWorkingName:@"Users context"];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(usersContextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:_usersContext];
}


- (void)getAllUsers
{
    // async server call with main thread callback :
        [self.usersContext performBlock:^{
            // ... create/update/delete users in usersContext with server objects
            [self.usersContext MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait]; // will call usersContextDidSave:
        }];
    // end of server callback
}


- (void)usersContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (notification.object == self.usersContext) {
        [self.contactsContext performBlock:^{
            [self.contactsContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
            // delete all users not contacts from contactsContext
            [Users deleteAllMatchingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contact != 1"] inContext:self.contactsContext];
            [self.contactsContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:nil];
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't merge sibling contexts.  That is going to cause you problems.  Instances of `NSManagedObjectContext` are cheap and when you are using private queue contexts they are intended to be thrown away after **one** use.  Use them, throw them away, create a new one for the next piece of work that needs to be done.

No merging of change notifications required.

Comment: So each time I call server, I create 2 contexts ? One for all users create/update/delete to be shown and one to save contacts only ?

Comment: Why do you need two? Are you saving to more than on stack? If not then a single private context should be more than sufficient per data call.

Comment: If I use one context, it will update UI with all users. Then if I delete all users that are not contacts (to keep contacts only) and save, they will disappear from UI. Maybe I need a completely different approach for what I want to do...

Comment: I would suggest a different approach.  If you want your UI to show a subset then it should filter on the data, you are using/abusing a quirk of parent/child contexts that might go away on you.  Better to do data level filtering and a single import context (one at a time anyway).  Your app will be happier and more robust.

Comment: OK I now realize that my approach is too complicated (maybe I'm too smart :) ). I will filter at data level and everything will work perfectly. Thanks for all your tips. Regards